# Restructuring & renaming of a specific file structure based on country code

Tags: bash

I have a file structure like the one below:

```
Localizable
Localizable_en
Localizable_de
Localizable_es
Localizable_zh_CN
Root
Root_de
Root_en
Root_es
Root_zh_CN
TechnicalSupportPane
TechnicalSupportPane_jp
TechnicalSupportPane_de
TechnicalSupportPane_es
TechnicalSupportPane_en
TechnicalSupportPane_zh_CN
```

I want to copy all files with _[Country Code] into a folder (mkdir) starting with this country code and rename the file. But there are files without a country code, these should be copied into the root folder ($TRANSLATION_FOLDER). And if a chinese country code is found like zh_CN this should be converted to zh-Hans.

I have the following coding so far, but there are the files without country code be ignored - or wrongly copied.

```
mkdir $SETTINGS_FOLDER
mkdir $TRANSLATION_FOLDER

for XLF in $( find "." -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.xlf" );
do

    TMP_LANGUAGE=${XLF: -6}
    LANGUAGE=${TMP_LANGUAGE:0:2}

    if [[ "$XLF" == *zh* ]]
    then
        LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER="zh-Hans.project"
    else
        LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER=$LANGUAGE".project"
    fi

    TMP_FILE_NAME=${XLF%.xlf}
    FILE_NAME=${TMP_FILE_NAME##*/}

    echo "Processing language "$LANGUAGE" with file "$FILE_NAME

    if [[ "$XLF" == *Localizable* ]]
    then
        echo "Processing Localizable" $XLF

        mkdir  $TRANSLATION_FOLDER"/"$LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER

        cp $FILE_NAME_STRING $TRANSLATION_FOLDER"/"$LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER"/Localizable"
    else
        echo "Processing Root and TechnicalSupportPane" $XLF

        mkdir  $SETTINGS_BUNDLE_FOLDER"/"$LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER
        cp $FILE_NAME_STRING $SETTINGS_FOLDER"/"$LANGUAGE_PROJ_FOLDER
    fi
done
```

I remove the file prefix and check for the country code at the end - this works for all files with country code but from the ones without the last to chars are taken - which is wrong.

Is there an efficient way of parsing these file structure with creating and copying these files?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be just to echo the commands that you want to do and then when you're sure it's right `| sh`.

The benefit is that you can eyeball the changes that will be made without the cp/mkdir etc being done.

I use this technique using `Perl` when I want to rename file using complex regexp.

**EDIT** Fuller example is reads from a **DATA** section for convenience.

```
use strict;
my $dest = "some-destination";
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $filename = $_;
    my($file, $cc) = m!(.+?)_(.*)!;
    $file = $_ unless $file;
    # Fix chinese zh_CN -> zh-Hans
    $cc =~ s!(.+)_CN!$1-Hans!;

    #print "# file=$file cc=$cc\n";

    if ( $cc ) {
        print "mkdir -p $dest/$cc\n";
        print "cp $filename $dest/$cc/$file\n";
    }
    else {
        print "cp $filename $dest\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
__DATA__
Localizable
Localizable_en
Localizable_de
Localizable_es
Localizable_zh_CN
Root
Root_de
Root_en
Root_es
Root_zh_CN
TechnicalSupportPane
TechnicalSupportPane_jp
TechnicalSupportPane_de
TechnicalSupportPane_es
TechnicalSupportPane_en
TechnicalSupportPane_zh_CN
```

Output which could be piped through `sh` if correct of course.

```
cp Localizable some-destination

mkdir -p some-destination/en
cp Localizable_en some-destination/en/Localizable

mkdir -p some-destination/de
cp Localizable_de some-destination/de/Localizable

mkdir -p some-destination/es
cp Localizable_es some-destination/es/Localizable

mkdir -p some-destination/zh-Hans
cp Localizable_zh_CN some-destination/zh-Hans/Localizable

cp Root some-destination

mkdir -p some-destination/de
cp Root_de some-destination/de/Root

mkdir -p some-destination/en
cp Root_en some-destination/en/Root

mkdir -p some-destination/es
cp Root_es some-destination/es/Root

mkdir -p some-destination/zh-Hans
cp Root_zh_CN some-destination/zh-Hans/Root

cp TechnicalSupportPane some-destination

mkdir -p some-destination/jp
cp TechnicalSupportPane_jp some-destination/jp/TechnicalSupportPane

mkdir -p some-destination/de
cp TechnicalSupportPane_de some-destination/de/TechnicalSupportPane

mkdir -p some-destination/es
cp TechnicalSupportPane_es some-destination/es/TechnicalSupportPane

mkdir -p some-destination/en
cp TechnicalSupportPane_en some-destination/en/TechnicalSupportPane

mkdir -p some-destination/zh-Hans
cp TechnicalSupportPane_zh_CN some-destination/zh-Hans/TechnicalSupportPane
```

Noddy Example from the command line whereas yours would be a script.

```
bash-3.2$ echo "cat t1"
cat t1

bash-3.2$ echo "cat t1" |sh
0.2 1.45
0.3 1.67
0.1 1.23
1e-2 1.23
0.2 1.45
1e-1 1.23
0.3 1.67
0.3 1.67
0.4 1.78
0.5 1.89
```